# materializecss search bar is not working properly in chrome

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, materialize

I was creating the design of a website using materializecss with no problems in firefox, until i checked it again in Chrome.

Well, everything is working fine except the search bar, i am using the navbar mentioned in the documentation so i guess nothing is wrong with the code, and it works in firefox.

## Firefox Screenshot:

[image]

## Chrome Screenshot:

[image]

## HTML code:

```
  <form class="hide-on-med-and-down">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input id="search" type="search" required>
      <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
      <i class="material-icons">close</i>
    </div>
  </form>
```

I did change the `CSS` of the search bar to this (i found that in a solution to a similar problem in here):

```
nav .nav-wrapper form, nav .nav-wrapper form .input-field{
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to share what is going on with you blue bar html and css to see what is in play here.

Comment: Thank you @CarolMcKay for your comment.
The blue bar, is a navbar that contains links on the left, logo in the middle and Dropdown and search bar in the right, the dropdown in the right changes languages.

Comment: and the css you are using to make this layout work? or is it just laid out according to the content?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your question, but if you are asking about the language switching i am using `html5` data attribute and a `json` dictionary to translate each element i want to translate by itself, the dropdown has nothing special, it is only binded to a `click event`.
Everything else in the navbar is the default that i have found in `Materializecss` documentation

Comment: I haven't worked with Materialize but please see my answer for the css that might work for you.

Comment: I will, i appreciate it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183043/discussion-between-carol-mckay-and-yak0d3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css:

```
.nav-wrapper {
  width:100%;
  background:blue;
  /* this will automatically make the items it contains stretch verically */
  display:flex; 
  justify-content:space-between;
}

/* the form is in your float right unordered list (ul) so add this to fix the chrome layout issue */
.nav-wrapper ul[class="right"] {
  display:flex;
}

form {
  /* don't let the blue bleed through */
  background:white;
}

 /* if you want it to be responsive pick your number and add this css */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

link about flex layouts: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but i am still having the same problem with the google chrome browser..

Comment: do you have a test site I can see?